# По окончании или по окончанию?

Tags: окончания

*Надеюсь, что по окончании конференции...* Верно ли окончание в "по окончании"?

Answer (score 2):

> *Надеюсь, что по окончании конференции...* Верно ли окончание в "по окончании"?

Верно.

[**См. словарь:**](http://orthography.academic.ru/23612/%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

> ***по окончании***, предлог с род.
>
> *По окончании экзамена все пошли в кино.*
>
> **Слитно. Раздельно. Через дефис...** Б. З. Букчина.

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от того, что говорится дальше...

> Надеюсь, что по окончани**и** конференции участники не разъедутся сразу, а
>   останутся на банкет.
>
> Надеюсь, что по окончани**ю** конференции, которое ознаменовалось
>   скандалом, журналисты не станут судить о её научной значимости.

Comment: Второй случай с существительным "окончание".