# По окончанИИ или по окончанИЮ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

Как правильно:
*По **окончании** этого представления?*

Или:
*По **окончанию** этого представления?*

Какое правило здесь применяется?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [По окончании или по окончанию?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427404/%d0%9f%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: Вопрос тот же, да ответы были невразумительные: вразнобой.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же, правильно *по окончан**ии***. Падеж предложный, не дательный.

Вот почему, это сложный вопрос. Может, кто-то Вам на него и ответит, но я лишь нашёл указание на случаи его употребления с предлогом ***по***. Смотрите [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8) вопрос № 280859:

> Предлог по употребляется с предложным падежом при указании действия, события, после которого что-либо совершается: *по приезде друга, по возвращении из отпуска, **по окончании** спектакля.*

Comment: Не хотелось оставлять это "да" в цитате. Многоточие тоже не хотелось ставить при пропущенном одном слове. Но ведь если бы я начал с "предлога", цитата была бы оформлена неправильно, верно? Или так всё-таки можно? Кто подскажет?

Comment: Я бы запросто начала с предлога. Мы же не некий канонический текст цитируем.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Тогда уберу лишнее с радостью.)